# App Store disables downloading of macOS Sierra

Tags: mac-appstore, macos

[image]I've been trying to download OSX "EC" (10.11) for the last week in order to make a recovery USB. The download always fails at exactly 1.92Gb.

Now that macOS Sierra has been released I notice that the 10.11 download has been removed from the App Store.

However, the macOS Sierra download also failed after several Gb, but unlike the 10.11 download I'm physically unable to re-attempt the download- please see the attached screenshot.

I've had a quick look over the stack of App Store related questions but none seems to have solved it. 
Anyone please any ideas? I can't even seem to create a working .zip of a good download from another machine.

Comment: As it stands, this isn't really answerable. Could you clarify your question. First of all, you refer to "EC" which judging from your screenshot is El Capitan, yet you also refer to 10.6 which was Snow Leopard. El Capitan is 10.11. Secondly, which of the 3 points would you like to fix? Downloading Sierra, downloading El Capitan, or indeed 'creating a working zip from another machine' ? Thirdly, what machine & OS are you currently on?

Comment: Sorry, not a big fan of the name 'el Capitan', but yes, I've updated the version to 10.11, apologies. Ideally, I'd like to know if anyone has experienced the same issue, and knows how I might be able to untangle the App Store and download the sierra installer? The button, as in the screenshot, is disabled and despite all attempts doesn't return to a state where I can click it. Unless anyone knows where I can find the 10.11 installer? OSX 10.11.6, it's a MacMini if you're interested.

Comment: Many things to try: restarting your router, a SMC reset, or even a PVRAM reset.

Comment: Using Terminal, go into your `Applications` folder (`cd /Applications`)  If there is a folder that's named `Install OS X El Capitan` or `Install macOS Sierra` then delete it/them.  Retry your download.

Comment: Try resetting your DNS: [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT202516)

Comment: Thanks- I've tried a number of resets, including the router, machine and flushing the DNS cache. I didn't try resetting the SMC or P/NV/RAM as I thought it would be a bit drastic. All I wanted was to be able to click the button again. Thanks for all your suggestions though- has anyone solved a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this article and link:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208202 -  How to download macOS Sierra
- [macOS Sierra Installer on the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414?ls=1&mt=12)

I would use the [help article HT20802](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208202) to check for an updated link if the Mac App Store one fails you.