# How to upgrade from OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 to macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: macos, upgrade, high-sierra

I have OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6 installed and want to upgrade to macOS Sierra 10.12.6

I have downloaded macOS Sierra version 10.13

I have .dmg file of macOS Sierra 10.12.6 but when I am going install it gives me the following error:

[image]

I found a lot of .dmg of version 10.12 but I didn't get anywhere then I got version 10.12.1.

Now I am confused that do I compulsory need to fine 10.12 and install it and than after update 10.12.4 and than after 10.12.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have downloaded some updater files for macOS Sierra which require at least an already installed macOS Sierra 10.12.

They are useless if OS X 10.11 El Capitan is installed.

Go to the App Store, download the macOS Sierra installer and install it. If it isn't available the following trick may help:

> Mission accomplished: after installing this command-line tool ('https://github.com/mas-cli/mas'), the command
>   `mas install 1127487414`
>   purchased*, downloaded, and installed version 10.12.6 of correctly.
>
> * By which I mean, the program not only downloaded Sierra, it did so using the Apple-supplied App Store frameworks in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks, resulting in an application bundle containing a properly-signed MAS receipt linked to my Apple ID.

or try bmike's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/302546/93229).

Answer (score -2):

You’re too late to download and install Sierra, 10.12. Only High Sierra, 10.13 is now available, and you’ll need to install that. The Sierra 10.12.6 file you have downloaded is a point update for 10.12, not a complete version, and can only be used to update an existing Sierra installation.

Comment: While the last sentence is true, the first two are false: it is incorrect to state that one is "too late" — there's no time limit on installing compatible versions of macOS.